# Python Version Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to fix an error in my python version and I stupidly ran the line:
`alias python=/Library/Python/2.7/python`

Once I realized that I had made a mistake I ran the line:
`unalias python`

After I continue to get this error message whenever I run a python command, which I think has to do with having two different python versions:

```
File "site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Have you tried opening a new shell window? Shell `alias` commands aren't persisted automatically unless you put them explicitly into `.profile` or similar configuration files.

Comment: I think you should give more description for your question. 1. what you r purpose  is; 2. what OS you use; 3. what did you done and what error came out step by step.

Comment: Please post the command and the code which you are trying to run